# Make a matrix from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of table - input]

I want to create a matrix that will count the number of times each time per 'ID',  'col2' and 'col3' says a fruit value:

[image: screenshot of table - output]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or table formatting. It also wouldn't hurt to provide code that creates this df; see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (vectorized):

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df.to_numpy()[:, None] == np.unique(df.to_numpy())[:, None], axis=2), index=df.index, columns=np.unique(df.to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     Apple  Orange  Pear
ID                      
001      0       2     0
002      1       0     1
003      1       0     1
```

If you want to operate on only a subset of the columns:

```
subset = ['col2', 'col3']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.sum(df[subset].to_numpy()[:, None] == np.unique(df[subset].to_numpy())[:, None], axis=2), index=df.index, columns=np.unique(df[subset].to_numpy()))
```

Comment: what if the data frame contains more columns, but I only want to look at col 2 and col 3

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
dicts = [df.loc[idx].value_counts().to_dict() for idx in df.index]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicts, index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output df2:

```
     Orange   Pear   Apple
ID          
001       2      0       0
002       0      1       1
003       0      1       1
```